# Execute event on first click only

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I’m trying to execute the below click(function) only on first click, but it always executes whenever I click on the map.
Is it possible to use One-Click with the below code ? Thanks in advance

```
var placedMarkers = 0;
var availableMarkersToPlace = 1;
setTimeout( function(){
    if(placedMarkers >= availableMarkersToPlace)
         return;
    placedMarkers++;
    var map = Appery("google_map").gmap;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { 
       localStorage.setItem('selectedLat', event.latLng.lat());
localStorage.setItem('selectedLng', event.latLng.lng()); 
        placeMarker(event.latLng,map);  
        alert(event.latLng);
    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.
I'm not much of a JS guy, but I would go ahead and add a boolean switch for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create flag-value, which will decide, run your function  or skip:

```
var placedMarkers = 0;
var availableMarkersToPlace = 1;
var clicked = false;

setTimeout( function(){
    if(placedMarkers >= availableMarkersToPlace)
        return;
    placedMarkers++;
    var map = Appery("google_map").gmap;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) { 
        if(!clicked) {
            clicked = true;
            localStorage.setItem('selectedLat', event.latLng.lat());
            localStorage.setItem('selectedLng', event.latLng.lng()); 
            placeMarker(event.latLng,map);  
            alert(event.latLng);            
        }

    });

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not really good at Javascript. How would this flag-value fits into my code above ?

Comment: I jsut want to show you the main idea, but. I've updated code

Answer (score 1):

Use addListenerOnce

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event) { 
   localStorage.setItem('selectedLat', event.latLng.lat());
   localStorage.setItem('selectedLng', event.latLng.lng()); 
    placeMarker(event.latLng,map);  
    alert(event.latLng);
});
```